# My avatar for Mario won't jump as I intend

Tags: java

I am programming a Mario game for my project for my computer science class, and so far the Mario character can run left and right, crouch, and I have built the background.

Two questions that I have are

1. when making the background move, should I make a separate class that has all the background images? This way I can switch out the various backgrounds I intend to create.
2. My current program has the issue of when I try and jump (press the up arrow key), Mario does not jump normally, he lags a bit and then rises a lot. I am trying to make it so Mario can rise lets say, one pixel every 100th of a second, but that is not working, instead, it waits around 1 or 2 seconds then rises 100 pixels and stops.

**Frame Class:**

```
    package FirstPlatformer;


  import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PlatformerFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //change to match your values for width/height
        //these can be changed
        int w = 1525;
        int h = 830;
        
        //sets up a JFrame object with title "Template"
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Template");
        //make sure the jframe closes when you hit the 'x'
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //adds the drawing panel to the frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Platformer(w,h));
        //resizes the frame to fit the panel
        frame.pack();
        //makes it visible
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

**Platformer Class:**

```
    package FirstPlatformer;



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


//change to be your packagename
//all imports are necessary


//must 'extend' JPanel 

public class Platformer extends JPanel
{
    
    Random test = new Random();
    Color aboveground = new Color (99, 158, 169);
     private ImageIcon marioStart, ground, mysteryBlock, smallMarioRight, smallMarioLeft, smallMarioCrouchedLeft, smallMarioCrouchedRight;
    //variables for the overall width and height
    private int w, h;

    boolean start = false;
    
    
    //crouching mechanism
    boolean crouchPressed = false;
    boolean crouchReleased = false;
    boolean youAreCrouching = false;
    
    //facing direction mechanisms
    boolean facingRight = true;
    boolean facingLeft = false;
    
    //jumping mechanisms
    boolean jumpStart = false;
    int jumpCountEqual = 0;
    
    
    private int number = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    
    int baseHeight = 770;
    int smallMarioGround = 725;
    //variable that establishes marios x coord
    int marioX = 0;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    //sets up the initial panel for drawing with proper size
    public Platformer(int w, int h)
    {

        setFocusable(true);
        
        
        
        
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        
//creating the images
        marioStart = new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/marioStart.JPG");
        
        //building blocks
        ground = new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/ground.JPG");
        mysteryBlock = new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/mysteryBlock.png");
        
        //small mario actions
        smallMarioLeft = new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/smallMarioRight.png");
        smallMarioRight = new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/smallMarioLeft.png");
        smallMarioCrouchedLeft = new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/marioCrouched.png");
        smallMarioCrouchedRight= new ImageIcon("src/FirstPlatformer/marioCrouchedRight.png");
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseTracker());
        this.addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
        
    }
    
    
    //all graphical components go here
    //this.setBackground(Color c) for example will change background color
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //this line sets up the graphics - always needed
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        
        
        //all drawings below here:
        
        //creating the starting screen
        if(start != true) {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        marioStart.paintIcon(this,g,240,100);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
        g.drawString("Created by Zane Lanski", 515, 625);
        g.drawString("Press Space to Start", 525, 725);
        
        }
else {
            //setting the overall background for when mario is aboveground
            setBackground(aboveground);
        
            //variable for building the bottom of the level
            int groundCount = 0;
            
            
            //for loop creates the base of the level
        for(int groundBase = 0; groundBase <30; groundBase++)   
        {
            
            ground.paintIcon(this, g, groundCount, 770);
            groundCount = groundCount + 52;
        
        }
            mysteryBlock.paintIcon(this, g, 500, 500);
        
            if(crouchPressed != true && facingRight == true) {
            smallMarioRight.paintIcon(this,g,marioX,smallMarioGround);
                
            }
            
            if(crouchPressed != true && facingLeft == true) {
                smallMarioLeft.paintIcon(this,g,marioX,smallMarioGround);
                    
                }
            
            if(crouchPressed != false) {
                smallMarioCrouchedRight.paintIcon(this,g, marioX, smallMarioGround+18);
            }
            
            if(jumpStart == true) {
                
                for(int jumpCount = jumpCountEqual;jumpCount < 100; jumpCount++) {
                
                    smallMarioGround = smallMarioGround- 1;
            //  smallMarioRight.paintIcon(this, g, marioX, smallMarioGround);   
                 try
                 {
                     Thread.sleep(10);
                 }
                 catch(InterruptedException e)
                 {
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }    
                 repaint();
                 System.out.println(jumpCount);
                 jumpCountEqual++;
                 
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        }
        
    }


    
    private class MouseTracker implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    
        
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            

            number++;
            count++;
            number %= 5;
            
            repaint();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    private class Keyboard implements KeyListener
    {
        
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            
            
            repaint();
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            
                    facingLeft = false;
                    facingRight = true;
                
                
                marioX = marioX + 5;
                
                facingRight = true;
                facingLeft = false;
                
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                
                
                
                crouchPressed = false;
                marioX = marioX - 5;
                facingLeft = true;
                facingRight = false;
                
                
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                crouchPressed = true;
                youAreCrouching = true;
            }
            
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                jumpStart = true;
            }
            
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                start = true;
            }
            
            repaint();
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                crouchPressed = false;
            }
            repaint();
            
        }
        
    }

    
    
    
}
```

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but you're trying to sleep in `paintComponent` which is a big no-no. In fact you should not need to sleep at all.

Comment: Joachim is correct. Your entire `if(jumpStart == true)` block **must not** be in a painting method. Remove that `sleep` call entirely, and use a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) (*not* java.util.Timer!) to perform your jump animation.  You will need to make `jumpCount` a private field rather a than local variable. In general, painting methods should only draw things; they should never, ever change the state of objects, because the system decides when painting methods are called, and programs have little control over it.